# How do I configure VSCode to open files like it does on Linux instead of using the Finder on Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I usually open files/folders using the <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> keys. When I'm connected to a Linux server via SSH I get a somewhat "native" looking file selection option thing but when I'm on my Mac I get the Finder. I don't want to get the Finder. Is there any way to configure this?

Comment: VSC asks the OS/Desktop to open a File Select dialog, the OS decides.

Comment: @rioV8 So I guess as long as I'm using macOS, then no, huh. :(

Comment: @starball Actually yes. Thanks! I'll close my question.

Comment: if there was anything about the question post there that made it difficult to search for (such as missing keywords that you tried searching for), consider making edits to improve/increase the searchability of the dup-target question.